# Cyclic quadrilateral, and isogonal conjugates?

Tags: geometry

I have a question regarding anti parallels, cyclic quadrilaterals, and the isogonal conjugate.

1. Given a cyclic quadrilateral, call the intersection of points the diagonals K. Prove that the line through the orthocenter of triangle ABK and K passes through the circumcenter of triangle CDK.

I know that AB and CD are antiparallel, and that the conjugate point of the orthocenter is the circumcenter; However, I'm not getting the solution.

Can anyone provide a intuitive approach to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ahm. You wrote ''Prove that the line through the orthocenter of triangle ABK...''. But the line should be determined by two points. Do you mean that the second point is K?

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad. That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\angle BAC =x$. By inscribed angle theorem, $\angle BDC = x$.

Now, if H is the orthocenter of ABK, $\angle AKH = 90^\circ - x$.

If O is the circumcenter of DCK, $\angle KOC = 2x$ and $\angle OKC = 90^\circ-x$.

That's all

[image]